How to send multiple images to Dall-e image variation api?
The openai image variation api accepts one image in the request docs. However, on the UI Dall-e accepts multiple images. I want to be able to do that through the api call as well. Is this done through context of some type?
My goal to call the variation api on multiple images as input and output 1-2 images.
